# How to get image from responsive canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to generate a final image of 1200x630 from 2 canvas that is not necessarily to have that size, for example to see the application from a mobile device.

This is the part of the canvas , I am drawing pictures and items according to user actions, it works.

```
<div>
    <canvas width="1200" height="630" id="canvas-foto">Tu navegador no soporta esta aplicaci&oacute;n</canvas>
    <canvas width="1200" height="630" id="canvas-marco">Tu navegador no soporta esta aplicaci&oacute;n</canvas>
    <canvas width="1200" height="630" id="canvas-wrapper">Tu navegador no soporta esta aplicaci&oacute;n</canvas>
</div>
<button id="btn_guardar">Guardar</button>
```

This would be part of JS responsible for generating the image, for example simply loose on screen, although I keep it on the server.

```
var canvas_marcos = document.getElementById("canvas-marco");
var ctx_marcos = canvas_marcos.getContext("2d");
var canvas_foto = document.getElementById("canvas-foto");
var ctx_foto = canvas_foto.getContext("2d");
var canvas_wrapper = document.getElementById("canvas-wrapper");
var ctx_wrapper = canvas_wrapper.getContext("2d");

$('#btn_guardar').click(function(){
    ctx_wrapper.drawImage(canvas_foto, 0, 0);
    ctx_wrapper.drawImage(canvas_marcos, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas_wrapper.toDataURL();

    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function(){
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    img.src = dataURL;
});
```

Now I have to implement this responsive, but rescaling the canvas size, the final image will also change. How do I get an image of 1200x630 from a smaller canvas?

Clarify that the elements inside the canvas can be relocated by the user via drag & drop.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the canvas display size with CSS.  This example sets the width to 100% shrinking or growing the image without altering the canvas.

```js
var canvas_marcos = document.getElementById("canvas-marco");
var ctx_marcos = canvas_marcos.getContext("2d");
var canvas_foto = document.getElementById("canvas-foto");
var ctx_foto = canvas_foto.getContext("2d");
var canvas_wrapper = document.getElementById("canvas-wrapper");
var ctx_wrapper = canvas_wrapper.getContext("2d");

$('#btn_guardar').click(function() {
  ctx_wrapper.drawImage(canvas_foto, 0, 0);
  ctx_wrapper.drawImage(canvas_marcos, 0, 0);

  var dataURL = canvas_wrapper.toDataURL();

  var img = new Image();
  img.style.position = "absolute";
  img.style.left = "0";
  img.style.top = "0";
  img.style.width = "100%";

  img.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    this.addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
      reset();
    });
  }

  img.src = dataURL;
});

// added by me

function toggleCanvas() {
  $(this).toggleClass('off');
  var can_id = "canvas-" + this.id.replace("btn_", "");
  $('#' + can_id).toggleClass('hide');
}

$('#btn_foto').click(toggleCanvas);
$('#btn_marco').click(toggleCanvas);
$('#btn_wrapper').click(toggleCanvas);


function clear(ctx, color, text, y_offset) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  var w = ctx.canvas.width;
  var h = ctx.canvas.height;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.font = "50px sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText(text, w / 2, h / 2 + y_offset);
}

function reset() {
  clear(ctx_foto, "rgba(0,0,0,.7)", "canvas-foto", 0);
  clear(ctx_marcos, "rgba(0,100,0,.7)", "canvas-marco", 50);
  clear(ctx_wrapper, "rgba(10,30,130,.7)", "canvas-wrapper", 100);
}

reset();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#canvas-foto,
#canvas-marco,
#canvas-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#controls {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00CC66;
  padding: 10px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
button.off {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
}
button.off span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas width="1200" height="630" id="canvas-foto">Tu navegador no soporta esta aplicaci&oacute;n</canvas>
  <canvas width="1200" height="630" id="canvas-marco">Tu navegador no soporta esta aplicaci&oacute;n</canvas>
  <canvas width="1200" height="630" id="canvas-wrapper">Tu navegador no soporta esta aplicaci&oacute;n</canvas>
</div>
<div id="controls">
  <button id="btn_guardar">Guardar</button>
  <button id="btn_foto">foto <span>&#10003;</span>
  </button>
  <button id="btn_marco">marco <span>&#10003;</span>
  </button>
  <button id="btn_wrapper">wrapper <span>&#10003;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: great, it helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If what you need to store on the server is the final image after users have moved different objects on the canvas, the best solution IMO is to store the objects positions as a JSON string and redraw it instead of saving the rendered image.

You will end up with a far smaller data on your server, and your users would be able to modify again the display.

This way, you will be able to redraw it correctly on every screen size, avoiding the CSS jittering, and you will even be able to export at any size you want.

By using `ctx.scale()`, every drawing operations can even keep the same position for any scale, you'll only have to compute it for mouse events.

```js
(function() {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


  ////////////////////
  // Object Storage //
  ////////////////////

  // unfortunately, localStorage on stack-snippet  will throw a security exception ...
  /*
  // get saved from localStorage, could be from server as well
  var fromStorage = function(){
    var str = localStorage.getItem('objects');
   if(!str) return false;
   return JSON.parse(str);
   };
    
  // save to localStorage or server
  var toStorage = function(){
   localStorage.setItem('objects', JSON.stringify(objects));
   }
  */
  // ... so just show the string that could be saved on server
  var toStorage = function() {
    log.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(objects);
  };

  save.onclick = toStorage;

  // initiate the objects previously stored or default one

  // var objects = fromStorage() || [{...}] Once again won't work in stack-snippets
  var objects = [
    {type:'rect', x:900, y:360, width:100, height:100, color:'blue'},
    {type:'circle',  x:150, y:60, width:72, height:72, color:'red'},
    {type:'image', url:"http://lorempixel.com/500/500", x:500, y:250, width: 300, height:300}
  ];

  // initialise our canvas
  var init = function() {
    // set the canvas' size and get the ratio
    setSize(sizes[0]);

    // check if there are image to load
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      if (objects[i].type === 'image') {
        imagesToLoad++;
        loadImage(objects[i]);
      }
    }
    // if there's none, draw already
    if (!imagesToLoad) draw();
  };

  // we only pass the desired width since we'll get the height from the ratio
  var setSize = function(width) {
    // set the canvas width
    canvas.width = width;
    // get the ratio of the current width divided by the desired one
    // store it in the canvas element so we can use it after in mouse events
    var ratio = canvas.ratio = canvas.width / 1200;
    // set our canvas height
    canvas.height = ratio * 630;
    // set the context scale to the ratio so we don't care about it while drawing
    ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);
  }

  // the drawing part
  var draw = function() {
    // clear the canvas at the default size since we changed the context's scale
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 630);
    // iterate through our objects array
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      var obj = objects[i];
      // set the current color to the one of the object
      ctx.fillStyle = obj.color;
      // do different drawing operations based on object's type
      switch (obj.type) {
        case 'rect':
          ctx.fillRect(obj.x, obj.y, obj.width, obj.height);
          break;
        case 'circle':
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(obj.x + obj.width / 2, obj.y + obj.width / 2, obj.width / 2, Math.PI * 2, 0);
          ctx.fill();
          break;
        case 'image':
          ctx.drawImage(obj.img, obj.x, obj.y, obj.width, obj.height);
          break;
      }
    }
  };


  var imagesToLoad = 0;
  // a function to load all our image resources
  var loadImage = function(obj) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      obj.img = this;
      if (!--imagesToLoad)
        draw();
    }
    img.src = obj.url;
  };

  //////////////////
  // mouse Events //
  //////////////////

  var activeObjects;
  var mousedownHandler = function(e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = (e.clientX - rect.left) / canvas.ratio;
    var y = (e.clientY - rect.top) / canvas.ratio;
    activeObjects = getActiveObjects(x, y);
  };

  var mouseupHandler = function(e) {
    // we stopped dragging, reset the activeObjects array
    activeObjects = null;
  }

  var mousemoveHandler = function(e) {
    // if there is no object being dragged
    if (!activeObjects) return;
    // x and y coordinates have to be scaled by our actual ratio
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = (e.clientX - rect.left) / canvas.ratio;
    var y = (e.clientY - rect.top) / canvas.ratio;
    // iterate through all active objects
    for (var i = 0; i < activeObjects.length; i++) {
      // and update their position
      update(activeObjects[i], x, y);
    }
  };

  var getActiveObjects = function(x, y) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      var obj = objects[i];
      if (obj.x < x && obj.x + obj.width > x && obj.y < y && obj.y + obj.height > y)
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    if (!arr.length) return null;
    else return arr;
  };

  var update = function(obj, x, y) {
    obj.x = x - (obj.width / 2);
    obj.y = y - (obj.height / 2);
    draw();
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedownHandler);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupHandler);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler);


  /////////////////////////////
  // Button events (for demo) //
  /////////////////////////////

  // store different sizes for our canvas
  var sizes = [300, 200, 600, 3000];
  var currentSize = 0;
  resize.onclick = function() {
    // iterate through the sizes array
    setSize(sizes[++currentSize % sizes.length]);
    draw();
  };

  // randomise our objects shapes and position 
  rand.onclick = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var obj = objects[i];
        obj.x = Math.random() * 1000;
        obj.y = Math.random() * 500;
        obj.width = Math.random() * 500;
        obj.height = (obj.type === 'circle') ? obj.width : Math.random() * 500;
      }
      draw();
    }
    // Let's go !
  init();
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<button id="resize">resize canvas</button>
<button id="save">save</button>
<button id="rand">randomize</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<br><p id="log"></p>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/09yLcL8e/) where the saving to localStorage also works.